# Support of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=1/2$ if $x=j2^{-m}$, with $j\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, and $(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$; and $f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)$ doesn´t satisfy  the previous conditions. Then the question is: what is the support of $f(x,y)$ if we know that the support of a function is the closure of all the points $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)\neq0$? This in order to prove that the support of $f$ is compact (bounded and closed).

Comment: You seems to be assuming *a priori* that the support is bounded (as $\operatorname{supp}f \subseteq [-1,1]^2$), and the support is closed by definition.  If the goal is to show that the support is compact, what else is there to know?

Comment: Well,, yes, we know that the support of $f$ is contained in $[-1,1]^2$, but for example, if we take $m=2$ what is the support of $f$? Sorry if my questions seem obvious but I'm taking a course of introduction to analysis for the first time.

Comment: You seem to be confused about how the function is being defined.  The function is nonzero for any value of $x$ such that there *exist* $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x = j2^{-m}$.  You don't get to pick some value of $m$ and then compute the support of $f$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Then, just for curiosity, is the support  of $f$ the box $[-1,1]^2$ or the set {$(x,y)|j2^{-m},j\in\mathbb{Z},m\in\mathbb{N}, y\in[-1,1]$}?

Comment: The set $S = \{ (j2^{-m}, y) : j\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in\mathbb{N}, j2^{-m} \in [-1,1], y\in [-1,1]\}$ is the set of points where $f$ is nonzero.  This set consists of a bunch of vertical lines at at each of the dyadic rational numbers.  This is not the support of $f$, as the support is the *closure* of $S$. $S$ is dense in $[-1,1]^2$, hence $\overline{S} = [-1,1]^2$ is the support of $f$ (as noted in the answer below).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: But, again, I still find the question unclear.  Are you trying to determine the support of $f$, or are you simply trying to show that $f$ is compactly supported?  If the latter, then (1) the support is closed by definition, and (2) the support is bounded by construction of $f$.  Thus, by application of Heine-Borel, the support is compact.  Done.  You don't need to explicitly determine the support to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn´t clear. The idea of the exercise is to prove that the support of $f$ is compact but, since I didn´t have a course of set theory or some related, I don´t understand very well the concept of closure of a set (in reality my course is about integral calculus in several variables but many of my college say that it is a course of introduction to analysis). So I extended it as an example of the closure of a set, in this case the closure of {$(x,y)|x=j2^{-m}, j\in\mathbb{Z}, m\in\mathbb{N}, y\in [-1,1]$} and I wanted to see arguments on why $supp f =[-1,1]^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The support of the function is equal to $$\mbox{supp}f =[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$$
since the set $$A=\{(x,y): x=j2^{-k} , j\in \mathbb{Z} , k\in\mathbb{N} , y\in [0,1]\}$$
is dense subset of $[-1,1]\times [-1,1].$

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me